# curl to localhost fails in 20.04

Tags: networking, server, firewall, curl

I have host machine 20.04 and guest VM box 22.04

I am trying to run the curl command and on both machine getting the same error.

**Host running this:**

```
sudo ufw status 
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5000:5100/tcp              ALLOW       Anywhere                  
1433                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
1434                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       127.0.0.1                 
5000:5100/tcp (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
1433 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
1434 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

and yes there are repeated rules but I was getting the same error even before.

I have tried a combination of curl with localhost or 127.0.0.1 or :80 or :8080 and still got a similar error

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused
```

```
sudo netstat -tunlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1434          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1514/sqlservr       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1431          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1514/sqlservr       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      200812/cupsd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1169/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1169/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      923/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1121/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1514/sqlservr       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      200812/cupsd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:1431                :::*                    LISTEN      1514/sqlservr       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:1434                :::*                    LISTEN      1514/sqlservr       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1121/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 :::1433                 :::*                    LISTEN      1514/sqlservr       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           923/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           200814/cups-browsed 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54075           0.0.0.0:*                           987/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           22568/chrome        
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           22612/chrome --type 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           987/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::55564                :::*                                987/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*
```

Also here I got nothing when trying to see if port 80 or 8080 is listen

```
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1121/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1121/sshd: /usr/sbi 
uss:~$ sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :80
uss:~$ sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :8080
```

Comment: Have you setup any services to listen on port 80 or 8080? The output of `sudo netstat -tnlp` shows that you haven't.

Comment: can you be more specific about what services you re referring to? If you can share a link or some resources that would be helpful